# jQuery doesn't work for all records from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am retrieving records from database and for each records there is a read more.

When read more is clicked it should display the complete text, I made it with AJAX and jQuery, but the problem is that read more is working for the first record only, what may the problem be ?

I am retrieving records from database and for each records there is a read more.

When read more is clicked it should display the complete text , I made it with AJAX and jQuery, but the problem is that read more is working for the first record only, what may the problem be ?

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("#readmorenews").click(function(){
    var ID = $("#newsid").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/icac/displaycontent-ajax.php",
      beforeSend: function() { $('#loadergif1').show(); },
      complete: function() { setTimeout(function() {  
        $("#loadergif1").hide();}, 2000);
      },
      data: 'x='+ ID,
      success: function(data) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
          $("#bcz").hide();
          $("#bczx").hide();
          $("#dispn").html(data);
          var $divsz = $("#dispn");
          $divsz.fadeIn("slow");
        },1500);
      } 
    }); 
  });
});
```

php

```
<div id="test1" style="margin:3px;flex: 1;" class="container">
  <h4 style="background-color:#ccc;font-weight:bold;">Latest News </h4>
  <?php
    mysqli_query($con,"set names 'utf8'");
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `icac_content_tbl`,`content_images` WHERE cat_id = '2' AND content_id = cid  GROUP BY `icac_content_tbl`.`time_date` DESC LIMIT 2");        
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($rowCount > 0){ 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
            $time_date = $row['time_date'];    
    ?>

<div  style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;" class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
    <img   class="myImg" style="border:4px solid #ccc;box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #ccc;" class="media-object" width="150" height="120" src="/icac/static-img-news/<?php echo $row['image_name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['image_desc']; ?>">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;"  class="media-body">
    <h4  style="color:blue;" class="media-heading"><?php echo $row["content_title"]; ?></h4>
    <?php echo substr($row["content_body"],0,250)."..."; ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="newsid" value="<?php echo $row['content_id']; ?>"/>
     <br><a id="readmorenews" style="color:black;" href="javascript:void(0)"><font color="#9C9999">Posted on <?php echo  date("d-m-Y h:i a" ,$row["time_date"]+7200); ?> <br>Readmore&raquo;</font></a> 
<div style="display:none;" id="loadergif1"><img  width="40" height="40" src="/icac/static-img-style/giphy.gif"></div>
  </div>

    </div>
     <?php  }  ?>
    <!----------- showmore start ------------>
     <div  style="" class="show_more_mains" id="show_more_mains<?php echo $time_date; ?>">
        <span  style="" id="<?php echo $time_date; ?>" class="show_mores" title="Load more posts">Show more news</span>

  </div>   

      <?php } ?>
    </div>
     <!------------------------------------------    latest news end   ---------------------------------------->


</div>

<div  id="bczx" style="display: flex;" class="jumbotron">
<div  style="margin:3px; width: 52%;border-right:1px solid #ccc;" class="container">
    <h4 style="background-color:#ccc;font-weight:bold;">International Court News</h4>
    </div>

<div  style="margin:3px;flex: 1;" class="container">
    <h4 style="background-color:#ccc;font-weight:bold;">World News </h4>

    </di
```

v>

```
<div id="dispn"></div>
```

Comment: hi Nasralla, could you please edit your question to only include enough code to reproduce the problem?  In addition, it would help if you could improve the grammar of your question.  Finally, it's not totally clear what the problem is - could you clarify what output you get, and what output you want?  What do you mean by "it only works for the first record"?  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is due to the newsid which is not unique thats why each time you get the same id when you click the viewmore link.

Here is the working code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e){
    $("a[id^='readmorenews-']").click(function(){
     var i = $(this).attr('data-i');
 var ID = $("#newsid-"+i).val();
      $.ajax({


    type: "POST",
    url: "/icac/displaycontent-ajax.php",
           beforeSend: function() { $('#loadergif1').show(); },
        complete: function() { setTimeout(function() {  $("#loadergif1").hide();}, 2000);},
    data: 'x='+ ID,
    success: function(data) {
setTimeout(function() { 

    $("#bcz").hide();
                 $("#bczx").hide();
    $("#dispn").html(data);
var $divsz = $("#dispn");
$divsz.fadeIn("slow");},


           1500);


    } 


        }); 
});
});
```

PHP

```
<div id="test1" style="margin:3px;flex: 1;" class="container">
    <h4 style="background-color:#ccc;font-weight:bold;">Latest News </h4>

<?php


    mysqli_query($con,"set names 'utf8'");

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `icac_content_tbl`,`content_images` WHERE cat_id = '2' AND content_id = cid  GROUP BY `icac_content_tbl`.`time_date` DESC LIMIT 2");        
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($rowCount > 0){ 
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
            $time_date = $row['time_date'];    
            $i++;
    ?>

<div  style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;" class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
    <img   class="myImg" style="border:4px solid #ccc;box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #ccc;" class="media-object" width="150" height="120" src="/icac/static-img-news/<?php echo $row['image_name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['image_desc']; ?>">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;"  class="media-body">
    <h4  style="color:blue;" class="media-heading"><?php echo $row["content_title"]; ?></h4>
    <?php echo substr($row["content_body"],0,250)."..."; ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="newsid-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row['content_id']; ?>"/>
     <br><a data-i="<?php echo $i;?>" id="readmorenews-<?php echo $i;?>" style="color:black;" href="javascript:void(0)"><font color="#9C9999">Posted on <?php echo  date("d-m-Y h:i a" ,$row["time_date"]+7200); ?> <br>Readmore&raquo;</font></a> 
<div style="display:none;" id="loadergif1"><img  width="40" height="40" src="/icac/static-img-style/giphy.gif"></div>
  </div>

    </div>
     <?php  }  ?>
    <!----------- showmore start ------------>
     <div  style="" class="show_more_mains" id="show_more_mains<?php echo $time_date; ?>">
        <span  style="" id="<?php echo $time_date; ?>" class="show_mores" title="Load more posts">Show more news</span>

  </div>   

      <?php } ?>
    </div>
     <!------------------------------------------    latest news end   ---------------------------------------->


</div>

<div  id="bczx" style="display: flex;" class="jumbotron">
<div  style="margin:3px; width: 52%;border-right:1px solid #ccc;" class="container">
    <h4 style="background-color:#ccc;font-weight:bold;">International Court News</h4>
    </div>

<div  style="margin:3px;flex: 1;" class="container">
    <h4 style="background-color:#ccc;font-weight:bold;">World News </h4>

    </div>
```

Comment: could you explain what was the proble m ?

Comment: A good answer includes information about what the error was, what was changed and why. Just posting a bunch of code isn't that helpful for future visitors.

Comment: @NasrallaMohammad the problem is due to the newsid which is not unique thats why each time you get the same id when you click the readmore link.

Comment: @AbidNawaz  I will try it after I get home from my work and I will reply back

Comment: the loader is not showing in the other records ,,morover it isn't displaying any output

Comment: What you mean by loader here ?

Comment: the output worked correctly I was missing something the gif loader ,,it must show when pressing read more for every record

Comment: make the loader id as id="loadergif1-<?php echo $i>" and in the js code edit it as   $('#loadergif1-'+i).show();

Comment: yes  man thanks a lot ,, but I was wondering if there is any tutorial about making things unique in jquery and ajax

Comment: @NasrallaMohammad read this https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  and this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp